# Another proof that $A[x]\otimes M\cong M[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

Let $A$ be a ring and $M$ be an $A$-module. If $x$ is an indeterminate, I know that $A[x]\otimes_AM\cong M[x]$ ($A[x],M[x]$ are clearly $A$-modules). However my question is if one can prove this equality using the exact sequences, plus the facts that $M\otimes_A-$ is right-exact and that $A[x]\otimes _A-$ is exact.

Comment: Maybe try using that $A[x]=\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}Ax^n$ and that tensoring commutes with direct sums.

Comment: Is this a proof? $M\otimes_A \bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty (A)_n=\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty( M)_n=M[x].$ It should be ok since $Ax^n\cong A$ for any $n$